# Sending HTTP request's

Tags: java, html, sockets, request, serversocket

I am writing a web client. I have the following code.

```
public class Connection extends Thread{
public final static int PORT = 1337;
private ServerSocket svrSocket = null;
private Socket con  =  null;
public Connection(){

    try{
        svrSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Conected to: " + PORT);

    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
       System.err.println(ex);
       System.out.println("Unable to attach to port");
   }

}

public void run(){

while(true)
{

        try{
            con = svrSocket.accept();//on this part the program stops
            System.out.println("Client request accepted");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            out.println("GET /<index.html> HTTP/1.1");

            out.println("***CLOSE***");
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
           /*
            String s;

            while((s = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(s);
            }*/
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in.close();
            con.close();

            System.out.println("all closed");
    }
        catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }



}
}

}
```

The run method will be used latter on. That I have is a file called `index.html`. This file is in the same file as the java code. What I am trying to do with the request is send the HTML file. But if I run this program on a web browser `localhost:1337` the following gets displayed.

```
GET /<index.html> HTTP/1.1
***CLOSE***
```

This should not get displayed. The page that results of the HTML code in the `index.html` should get displayed.

Index.html code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>       </title>

 </head>
 <body bgcolor = "#ffffcc" text = "#000000">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>This is a simple web page</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

How do I get this html page to display in the browser?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t seems that all is good on your code, it seems you need to read the HTTP header from the input stream so you can get the requested file name and then use the Socket output stream to write the response from the file.

```
OutputStream output = con.getOutputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String fileName = readHeader(in);
String baseDir = System.getProperty("my.base.dir", "/home/myname/httpserver");
boolean exist = true;
InputStream fileIn = null;
try {
   File requestedFile = new File(baseDir, fileName);
   fileIn = new FileInputStream(requestedFile);
} catch(Exception e){
    exist = false;
}

String server = "Java Http Server";
String statusLine = null;
String typeLine = null;
String body = null;
String lengthLine = "error";

if (exist) {
   statusLine = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" + "\r\n";
   //get content type by extension
   typeLine = "Content-type: html/text  \r\n";
   lengthLine = "Content-Length: " + (new Integer(fileIn.available())).toString() + "\r\n";
} else {
  statusLine = "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found" + CRLF;
  typeLine = "text/html";
  body = "<HTML>" + "<HEAD><TITLE>404</TITLE></HEAD>" + "<BODY>404 Not Found"+"</BODY></HTML>";
}

output.write(statusLine.getBytes());
output.write(server.getBytes());
output.write(typeLine.getBytes());
output.write(lengthLine.getBytes());

output.write("\r\n".getBytes());

if (exist) {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int bytes = 0;

   while ((bytes = fileIn.read(buffer)) != -1) {
     output.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
   }
} else {
   output.write(body.getBytes());
}
//close sreams
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing a couple of things. First of all: what you are writing is a server, not a client.

Second: You are not following the HTT Protocol.

The line `GET /<index.html> HTTP/1.1` (which is wrong, it should be `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`) is a request that is sent by the client (like a web browser). Instead, it is your server sending this.

A quick solution:

Instead of sending this static text (the line with the `GET` and the one with the `***CLOSE***`), read the content of your `index.html` file and print it to your `out` stream.

EDIT: Here's a quick overview of the http data flow:

1. The client (e.g. a browser) connects to the server
2. The client sends it's request, something like

   ```
   GET /theFileIWant.html HTTP/1.1\r\n
   Host: localhost\r\n
   \r\n
   ```
3. at this point, the client usually stops sending anything and waits for the server to respond. That is called the "request/response" model.
4. The server reads the request data and finds out what it has to do.
5. The output (in this case: a file's content) is sent to the client, preceded by HTTP response headers.
6. The connection can be kept open or closed, depending on the HTTP headers of both client's request and server's response.

Comment: And if I want to see the response like 200 OK how would I do that?

Comment: Instead of ``out.println("GET /<index.html> HTTP/1.1");`` you use ``out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");``. Look at [this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Server_response)!

Comment: I understand that you are saying a quick solution is to read the file in to the output stream but will I still be able to verify OK 200? And if I use the correct syntax with the request the same happens. The HTML file does not get picked up.